# Calculation of tolerance of a resistor for voltage sensing

Tags: resistors, power-electronics, voltage-divider, tolerance, calculation

I want to calculate the tolerance of resistor accurately to run a simulation to simulate accuracy  of voltage sensor. The resistor I am using is CRCW0603330RFKEA - 330 Ω from Vishay and I can't see any information about long term endurance tolerance, soldering tolerance in datasheet. What I can see is its minimum tolerance is 1%. I want to ask how this ppm effect overall tolerance of resistor. What is meant by long term endurance tolerance, what is soldering tolerance? Below is the total tolerance calculated by this Vishay resistor in an application note and I want to understand how the total value is calculated using datasheet. If anyone could please assist me here. Thanks

- 1% Tolerance
- 100 ppm
- 2% Long term endurance
- 0.25& soldering
- total tolerance value=0.0408

Answer (score 1):

Essentially out of the reel it will be within 1% of the nominal resistance, after soldering it will be within .25% of the original value.  The resistance will change by no more than 100ppm per degree of temperature change and after whatever Vishal deem to be long-term endurance the value will not change my more than 2%.  I’d imagine that the total tolerance value is the worst case from new to old, allowing for soldering and over the entire temperature range.  It’s the most pessimistic value possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you also please explain how the total tolerance is been calculated using these four values in this case

Comment: Intuitively it would be all of the tolerances multiplied together, so the upper limit would be 1.01 * 1.02 * 1.0025 * (1+ 210 * 0.0001) but that gives a slightly larger figure, so presumably Vishay know somehow that the tolerances don’t all accumulate to worst case in the same direction.

Comment: how you added the ppm like this(1+ 210 * 0.0001). i did not understand this

Comment: the temperature range is -55 to +155 so total 210C and 100ppm = 0.0001 per degree.